# How to annotate to require individual elements of requestBody in springdoc?

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a spring (boot) server and want to generate the OpenAPI spec from the annotations with springdoc.

I have a request with two parameters in the request body. I want the first to be required and the second to be optional.

`@RequestBody(required = {true|false})` seems to only set all parameters in the body to (not) required.
The Javadoc for `@Parameter` on the other hand say to use `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody`

This is my code that I would expect to generate a spec where the first parameter is required and the second one is optional:

```java
@GetMapping("/fstVector")
public ResponseEntity<Vector> fstV(@RequestBody final Vector v1, @RequestBody(required = false) final Vector v2) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(v1, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping("/fstVector")
public ResponseEntity<Vector> fstVPost(@RequestBody(required = true) final Vector v1, @RequestBody(required = false) final Vector v2) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(v1, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The generated spec however has both parameters required:

```yaml
  /pond/fstVector:
    get:
      tags:
      - circle-escape-controller
      operationId: fstV
      parameters:
      - name: v1
        in: query
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Vector'
      - name: v2
        in: query
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Vector'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Vector'
    post:
      tags:
      - circle-escape-controller
      operationId: fstVPost
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                v1:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Vector'
                v2:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Vector'
        required: true
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Vector'
```

How can I require only a specific parameter for all four request types?

Comment: Ideally, a GET request should not take a request body (until you really want to send huge objects) and a POST request should not return `OK`

Comment: What are "all four request types"?

Comment: @ognjenkl GET, PUT, POST, DELETE

Comment: @peer How does the DELETE fit to "the first to be required and the second to be optional"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Important**

- There should not be more than 1 Request Body to a given endpoint!
- Request Body is mostly a JSON object. Thus to make some attribute in the body mandatory it's suggested to use the validation api.
- There are 2 `@RequestBody` annotations. One from the Spring framework `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody` and another from `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody`

Importantly, even when you use the `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody` from the Swagger library, you'll still need to use the `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody` to receive the actual object.

Refactoring the code as below should be helpful in your case

Controller Class

```java
@GetMapping("/fstVector")
public ResponseEntity<Vector> fstV(
    // we generally use @RequestParam for query parameters. Query parameters are generally optional and thus the "required" attribute of @Parameter defaults to "false"
    @Parameter @RequestParam final Vector v1, 
    // set @Parameter to TRUE if the parameter must be passed.
    @Parameter(required = true) @RequestParam final Vector v2 
) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(v1, HttpStatus.OK);
}
    
@PostMapping("/fstVector")
public ResponseEntity<Vector> fstVPost(
    // RequestBody objects are "required" by default. To make them optional, add "(required = false)"
    @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody   // Spring
    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody  // Swagger
    @Valid // Bean validation to ensure if the incoming object is valid
    final Vector v1
) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(v1, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

For domain object, refactor the DTO as below

DTO

```java
@Schema(description = "My DTO")
class Vector {
   // The below attribute is required
   @NotNull
   @Parameter(description = "my first attribute", required = true)
   String attribute1;

   // The below attribute is optional
   @Parameter(description = "my second attribute", required  = false)
   String attribute2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to add request body to GET request, even though you can... Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).

Controller class methods:

```java
    @GetMapping("/fstVector")
    public ResponseEntity<Vector> fstV(
            @RequestParam final Vector v1,
            @RequestParam(required = false) final Vector v2) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(v1, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/fstVector")
    public ResponseEntity<Vector> fstVPost(
            @Valid
            @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
            @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody
            final VectorRequest vectorRequest) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(vectorRequest.getV1(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

DTO object:

```java
    public class VectorRequest {
        @NotNull
        Vector v1;
        Vector v2;
    
        public Vector getV1() {
            return v1;
        }
    
        public void setV1(Vector v1) {
            this.v1 = v1;
        }
    
        public Vector getV2() {
            return v2;
        }
    
        public void setV2(Vector v2) {
            this.v2 = v2;
        }
    }
```

Parameter v1 is required, v2 is optional.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can describe request body parameter by [@Schema](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#schema) annotation.